# Update user photo in G Suite

Tags: ruby, google-api, google-api-ruby-client

I am trying to update the user photo for a G Suite user using the following code:

```
require 'google/apis/admin_directory_v1'
require 'googleauth'
require 'googleauth/stores/file_token_store'

require 'fileutils'

OOB_URI = 'urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob'
CLIENT_SECRETS_PATH = 'client_secrets.json'
CREDENTIALS_PATH = File.join(Dir.home, '.credentials',
                             "admin-directory_v1-ruby-quickstart.yaml")
SCOPE = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user"    

def authorize
  FileUtils.mkdir_p(File.dirname(CREDENTIALS_PATH))

  client_id = Google::Auth::ClientId.from_file(CLIENT_SECRETS_PATH)
  token_store = Google::Auth::Stores::FileTokenStore.new(file: CREDENTIALS_PATH)
  authorizer = Google::Auth::UserAuthorizer.new(
    client_id, SCOPE, token_store)
  user_id = 'default'
  credentials = authorizer.get_credentials(user_id)
  if credentials.nil?
    url = authorizer.get_authorization_url(
      base_url: OOB_URI)
    puts "Open the following URL in the browser and enter the " +
         "resulting code after authorization"
    puts url
    code = gets
    credentials = authorizer.get_and_store_credentials_from_code(
      user_id: user_id, code: code, base_url: OOB_URI)
  end
  credentials
end

# Initialize the API
service = Google::Apis::AdminDirectoryV1::DirectoryService.new
service.authorization = authorize

require "base64"    
pic = Base64.encode64(File.read('profilepic.png')).tr("+/", "-_")

photo = Google::Apis::AdminDirectoryV1::UserPhoto.new
photo.photo_data = pic

service.update_user_photo("user@domain.com", photo)
```

But then I'm getting the error `"invalid: Invalid Input: photoData (Google::Apis::ClientError)"`. I am starting to suspect that this might be a bug on the Client Library but I want to check first if someone else performed this successfully.

I have been able to update the photo in the ["Try it!" section here](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users/photos/update) using the base64 encoded string returned by `pic = Base64.encode64(File.read('profilepic.png')).tr("+/", "-_")` and I have been able to do it using the PHP Client Library. Am I correct in thinking this is a bug?

Comment: Please do not roll back good edits, Morfinismo - the title was rather brief, the body was rather chatty, and it could have done with some paragraphying. If you are unhappy with an edit, then an excellent first step is to ping the editor to say why, using their `@username`. All editors should be willing to hear you out. Note that "don't edit my posts" is not a valid reason to reject good edits - mutual editing is the whole point here.

Comment: @halfer Thank you for your enlightenment!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this is a very old question, but I was having the same problem and it turns out the google-api-client library automatically base64 encodes/decodes your photo_data, so you just need to pass it the file data instead of encoding it, otherwise it gets encoded twice and you'll experience a 400 error.

```
# Read file
photo_data = File.read(image_path)

# Create a UserPhoto object
user_photo_object = Google::Apis::AdminDirectoryV1::UserPhoto.new(photo_data: photo_data)

# Update Photo
directory.update_user(user_key, user_photo_object)
```